How can you add the latest Ubuntu repositories (noble-numbat) in Linux Mint? What are the repository settings?
I am using Linux Mint, and I want to install a couple of packages from the latest Ubuntu (noble-numbat).
I think I can do this via:
Synaptic > Settings > repositories (which opens Software Sources)
Then Additional repositories
Is that right?
What are the details to add?
E.g. deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble universe
